# Mac OS X cannot run GDB

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb

Computer setup: Mac OS X Yosemite

My gdb functions well before. But today,

When I try to use gdb to debug:

```
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /Users/JackZhao/Desktop/work/reviewC/pp 
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 627: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
(please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

I tried to add key chain like this;
http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/
and this:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

And restart my computer. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by setting the -p in the taskgated plist:

edit (as sudo): `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist`

```
        ... <snip> ...

        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/libexec/taskgated</string>
                <string>-sp</string>
        </array>
```

From the `taskgated` manual:

```
OPTIONS
 -p       Accepts the old (Tiger) convention that a process with a primary effective group of procmod or procview is allowed to get task ports. Without this option, this legacy mode
          is not supported.
```

reference: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/36727

Comment: This is not a very good solution - it will stop working with the release of Mac OS X 10.11, as it's no longer possible to edit files in `/System`.

Comment: @duskwuff so you down vote a working solution that's actually useful _today_ because it won't work in the next version of OS X? I literally only found this question because I was trying to solve the same issue and I need a later version of gdb (ggdb) than what's installed natively.

Comment: El Capitan is *extremely* close to release - there's a public release candidate available, and RTM will probably be within the next few weeks. This isn't a matter of "it'll stop working eventually"; it's going to stop working very soon.