# How to get gdb to work using macports under OSX 10.11 El Capitan?

Tags: macos, gdb, macports

This arose from [How to install gdb (debugger) in Mac OSX El Capitan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162757/how-to-install-gdb-debugger-in-mac-osx-el-capitan).

I have macports working under el capitan no problem and have installed the gdb port but I can't get the codesigning to work. It all seems to have worked. The certificate is there and "Always Trust" is set. The binary shows:

```
$ codesign -d -v -v /opt/local/bin/ggdb 
Executable=/opt/local/bin/ggdb
Identifier=org.gnu.gdb
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=25320 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1261+2 location=embedded
Signature size=1392
Authority=gdb-cert
Signed Time=23 Oct 2015, 07:56:53
Info.plist entries=4
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=88
```

but I get

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/sal/Katiss/ecodriving 
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 39278: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
(please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

when I try to start debugging something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I just settled this problem by using the following command.

`sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a yourusername -t user procmod`

Which adds you to group `procmod`.

It's just because only users in `procmod` can use function `task_for_pid`, and you can find that the own group of `/opt/local/bin/ggdb` is `procmod`.

Comment: This does not solve it for me.  Do you need to reboot or restart your session?

Comment: There are two separate alternatives: for `procmod` group members to be permitted to run a custom gdb, the -p option must be added to `taskgated`.  The other option is to sign the binary, and add users to the `_developer` group. See my summary at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221969/4402721

Comment: This fixed it for me too. I imagine the ggdb binary's ownership is the issue, since membership of procmod is not a requirement per se - my own tools that use task_for_pid (owned by user tom, group staff) were unaffected by my  quote-unquote upgrade to El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

I installed MacPorts `gcc9` (gcc-9.2.0) on an older iMac (10.11.6 El Capitan), and recently needed to install the `gdb` port (gdb-9.1.0); predictably encountering the same code-signing / permission issue.

There's a list of instructions on [github](https://gist.github.com/hlissner/898b7dfc0a3b63824a70e15cd0180154) that worked perfectly for me, simply replacing: `/usr/local/bin/gdb` with: `/opt/local/bin/ggdb`. Since such snippets on github may be ephemeral, so I'll paste it here:

1. Open Keychain Access
2. In the menu, open **Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create a certificate**
3. Give it a name (e.g. `gdbc`)

   - Identity type: Self Signed Root
   - Certificate type: Code Signing
   - Check: let me override defaults
4. Continue until it prompts you for: "specify a location for..."
5. Set Keychain location to System
6. Create a certificate and close assistant.
7. Find the certificate in System keychains, right click it > get info (or just double click it)
8. Expand **Trust**, set **Code signing** to `always trust`
9. Restart taskgated in terminal: `killall taskgated`
10. Enable root account:

    1. Open System Preferences
    2. Go to User & Groups > Unlock
    3. Login Options > "Join" (next to Network Account Server)
    4. Click "Open Directory Utility"
    5. Go up to **Edit > Enable Root User**
11. Run `codesign -fs gdbc /usr/local/bin/gdb` in terminal: this asks for the root password
12. Disable root account (see #10)

Done!