# Exactly how do I install gdb on El Capitan?

Tags: macos, gdb, code-signing

I've reviewed [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162757/how-to-install-gdb-debugger-in-mac-osx-el-capitan) to this question, they fail for me, I lack reputation to comment there.  The other examples fail to be sufficiently detailed to know if I have misinterpreted one of the "do this" steps, or if there is some other problem.

I've created a self-signed certificate for code signing, I've signed gdb, I verified that I am in group _developer, and of course I rebooted.  I'm working with MacPorts so "gdb" is called "ggdb".  Here are commands that show how it looks for me:

```
% sudo codesign -s gdbc `which ggdb`
/opt/local/bin/ggdb: is already signed

% codesign --display --verbose=4 `which ggdb`
Executable=/opt/local/bin/ggdb
Identifier=org.gnu.gdb
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=26280 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1309+2 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=212cd20d95e5b5fb0cb1172647a1e18140e9650d
Signature size=1555
Authority=gdbc
Signed Time=Feb 18, 2016, 6:27:09 PM
Info.plist entries=4
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=88

% security find-identity -p codesigning

Policy: Code Signing
  Matching identities
  1) 2C6A7F0B4BBB757B90754A2DECCEA44B0B77856B "dlv-cert"
  2) ADCAD517D5E13C6DB95EDD6F89173F80DE81D14F "gdbc"
     2 identities found

  Valid identities only
  1) 2C6A7F0B4BBB757B90754A2DECCEA44B0B77856B "dlv-cert"
  2) ADCAD517D5E13C6DB95EDD6F89173F80DE81D14F "gdbc"
     2 valid identities found

% groups # ... shows perhaps confidential stuff I hope is irrelevant
5000 ... everyone netaccounts admin _appserveradm _lpadmin com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh ... _appstore _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_ftp com.apple.sharepoint.group.1

% dsmemberutil checkmembership -U $LOGNAME -G _developer
user is a member of the group
```

gdbc is a self-signed root certificate, marked trusted for all users:

[Certificate Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgHHk.png)

[KeyChainAccess overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM4nh.png)

Is there any other information that would help to diagnose this failure?
What *exactly* works for other people (I prefer codesigning to relaxing privileges in taskgated, which is "Alternative 2" in the link above).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to code-signing, I also had to do the following:

1)  Turn off SIP and modify taskgated invocation to include the -p flag (as is indicated when you use macports to install gdb)

2)  Add myself to the procmod group.  (See:  [How to get gdb to work using macports under OSX 10.11 El Capitan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298929/how-to-get-gdb-to-work-using-macports-under-osx-10-11-el-capitan) )

I spent all day yesterday trying to chase down the answers to this; the problem is that many of the answers seem to be getting pointed to as if they were still authoritative for El Capitan, but they're not (presumably do to SIP).

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I was able to get gdb working, once codesigned, just by adding myself to the procmod group (as described in the link). No logout required and I didn't have to change the taskgated arguments.