# remove user from group Mac Os X (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to remove myself from the groups _developer and procmod where I accidentally added it with the following commands:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a marinos -t user _developer
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a marinos -t user procmod
```

when I `id` I get this:

```
uid=501(marinos) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),9(procmod),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),204(_developer),502(access_bpf),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)
```

to remove I've tried

```
sudo dscl . -delete /Groups/_developer GroupMembership marinos
```

and I get this error

```
<main> attribute status: eDSAttributeNotFound
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14134 (eDSAttributeNotFound)
```

and this
    sudo dscl . -delete /Groups/procmod GroupMembership marinos
which results in no error but does not remove me from the group - `id` returns the very same groups as before.

I've also tried:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -u marinos -d procomod user procmod
```

and I get

```
Group not found.
```

and this:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -u marinos -d procmod user procmod
```

which results in no errors but has no effect either.. `id` still shows that I'm a member in all these groups..

please help... I'm desperate

Comment: Isn't there a GUID based ting going on anymore? This used to be the way -> ```dscl . -delete /Groups/<group> GroupMembers <GUID>``` GUID is the users GUID.

Comment: yes you're right! thanks.

Comment: i have added the answer

Comment: This has the best answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13132/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-on-command-line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way of removing a user from a group is using the GUID instead of the username:

```
dscl . -delete /Groups/<group> GroupMembers <GUID>
```

Comment: When you say GUID, do you mean UID? If so, then `dscl . -delete /Groups/<group> GroupMembers 501` does not work on High Sierra anymore...

Comment: @Drew I think he meant *GID* for Group ID, e.g. look at the results of `$ dscacheutil -q group`

Comment: I'm on mojave, how do you even find the GUID/UUID/UID of a user