# Most of my apps quit unexpectedly due to EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)

Tags: macos, code-signing

I've been trying to install GDB using macports and I followed both suggestions in the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162757/how-to-install-gdb-debugger-in-mac-osx-el-capitan). In short, the first method involves signing GDB with my own certificate and adding myself to the procmod and _developer groups. Once I found this did not work I tried the second method which involves disabling SIP and editing `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist`.

This second option did make GDB to work, but then suddenly more or less all apps in my system (but the  built-in mac os apps like safari, etc, would fail to launch with a 'quit unexpectedly' or with a 'is damaged and can’t be opened. Delete XX and download it again from the App Store' error.

All the crash reports (an indicative case is pasted at the end) mention a  EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid) exception so I assume that the whole problem has to do with some kind of setting I changed while trying to install GDB. I deleted the signature I'd created for this, I removed myself from _developer and procmod groups (at least I think I did), reverted the changes I did to  `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist` and the problem is still there.

Don't know what else to other than use time-machine to revert to some previous stable state, but this will cost me a several days of re-installing and copying things. Any ideas?

This is an indicative report of such  a crash:

```
Process:               Things [2735]
Path:                  /Applications/Things.app/Contents/MacOS/Things
Identifier:            com.culturedcode.things
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Things [2735]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-02-23 12:57:17.785 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F92433D6-4B65-2003-90E0-8C9AB4A742ED

Time Awake Since Boot: 2100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0x7fff7ad3a0a8 (cr2):
    __LINKEDIT             00007fff6283f000-00007fff62854000 [   84K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> Submap                 00007fff70000000-00007fff80000000 [256.0M] r--/rwx SM=PRV  process-only VM submap
    unused shlib __DATA    00007fff76fa4000-00007fff7b50a000 [ 69.4M] rw-/rw- SM=COW  system shared lib __DATA not used by this process

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                           0x00007fff627cc000 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000000000000d  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007fff5ee0bc38
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff627cc000  rfl: 0x0000000000000201  cr2: 0x00007fff7ad3a0a8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000f4
Trap Number:     133

Binary Images:
    0x7fff627cb000 -     0x7fff62802007  dyld (???) <9D05FDF4-65CE-3B53-86D4-ABE1A5BF35F3> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 2283
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0


VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=308K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=308K(100%)
Writable regions: Total=10.2M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=10.2M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
===========                     =======  =======
Process Corpse Info               2048K        2
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        2
Stack                             8192K        2
VM_ALLOCATE                          4K        2
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)               4K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                             240K        3
__LINKEDIT                          84K        2
__TEXT                             224K        2
mapped file                       2160K        4
shared memory                        8K        3
===========                     =======  =======
TOTAL                             68.7M       14
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    68.7M       14

Model: MacBookPro5,5, BootROM MBP55.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2,53 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.47f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313036374D2E433136464B44
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313036374D2E433136464B44
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB, 250,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Elements 10B8
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: My Passport 070A
Thunderbolt Bus:

MacBook Pro, OS X El Capitan (10.11.3)
```

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem. Did you finally fix it?

Comment: Hi, no. Not sure if anything has changed since then, but I switched to lldb eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows:

```
codesign --force --deep --sign Things.app
```

Perhaps this will help you to solve the problem.